# Hide parent component <button> element in Child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, quasar-framework

I'm trying to hide a button in my parent component in child component.I used props to bind the element and use v-show directive to hide it but instead of hiding the button, it hides the whole tab.

Here's my parent component:

```
<div class="col-lg-auto" v-if="unpaid.qr_code === 1">
    <q-btn glossy
           size="md"
           :label="$t('Common.GetQrCode.Button')"
            @click="makePayment(unpaidIndex, true)" color="positive"
            v-bind="share">
    </q-btn>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-auto" v-if="unpaid.qr_code === 1">
       -- OR --
</div>

props: {
  share: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
```

this component use in other component too  and as for my child component is

```
<payment-tab v-if="depositRefundID !== undefined && depositRefundID !== null && depositRefundID !== '' && loadingComplete" v-show:share="false">
```

Comment: Please properly format your codes next time.

Comment: Use v-else also

Answer (score 0):

It will be a good idea to hide the child.

Or if you want in this specific way, I had cracked the situation like that in react.

I will pass a function from parent to child; this function will update data in parent and that determins weather to show the child component.

```
new VueComponent('parent', {
    template: `
    <div class="...">
        <child-component v-for="obj in object_list" v-if="obj.show" />
    </div

    data: {
       object_list: [
           {show:true, id:1, ...},
           {show:true, id:2, ...},
           {show:false, id:3, ...}
       ]
    },
    methods: {
        toggle_show: function(item_id){
              let item = this.object_list.filter(_item => {_item.id === item_id})
              item.show = !item.show;
        }
    }
})
```